# Unable to access tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am running tomcat on google cloud debian machine. It is a basic tomcat, it starts up properly.However when I try to curl http://localhost:portnumber , it doesn't respond.

I already added address="0.0.0.0" or address="127.0.0.1" to my server.xml:
I have another springboot app on 8080 which runs fine.This is  for the finding ports:
Also if I
    telnet localhost portnumber it connects. What could be wrong?

```
<Connector port="50006" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="50007"  address="0.0.0.0"  />

sudo netstat  -plan | grep java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      
6634/java           
tcp6       5      0 127.0.0.1:50006         :::*                    LISTEN     
6566/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::50008                :::*                    LISTEN      
6566/java
```

Comment: Please show the exact telnet and curl command. Did you set http_proxy variables ? Curl uses them automatically, but not telnet

Comment: I use this for telnet
 `telnet localhost 50006
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'`                                                                                                                    This for curl                                                                                                                  `curl http://localhost:50006`

Comment: What about proxy variables ? What happens when you blindly type `GET /` into telnet and press ENTER ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment about proxy variables. I am justtrying to run it on localhost. Do i need to export http_proxy for that too? and for the GET / , here is what I get : `telnet localhost 50006
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
` just a blank screen